# SEO problems Google is indexing my web site URLs twice

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, url

I am having some issues with my website indexing. The thing is that I have a Website of news using PHP and MySQL. Every time that I create a news post a URL like this link the post.

Example:

```
   //pretty URL
   //nameOfSite + PostId + newsTitle

    mYpagExample.com/5/the-obama-lagacy
```

Google is indexing this 2 ways

```
    mYpagExample.com/5/  // Ii dont want this to be indexed
    mYpagExample.com/5/the-obama-lagacy
```

Even though I am declaring the original URL as canonical it seems to be no enough.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://mYpagExample.com/5/the-obama-lagacy">
```

NOTE: I am using `.htaccess` for the pretty URLs.

Can someone tell me how I can fix this?

**Edited**:

this is the link of the post that comes from the **DB** example:

```
  <a href="http://example.com/<?php echo $id?>/<?php echo $title?>/"><?php  echo $title?></a>
```

**.htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine on

# Get the request URL  by the user
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$ index.php?view=$1**
```

Comment: Have you tried modifying your robots.txt file?

Comment: what u men by modifying your robots.txt file? i got my  robots.txt normally  i mean `User-agent:*
Allow:/
Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap.xml`

Comment: https://seopressor.com/blog/how-to-control-web-crawlers/

Comment: The question is why is it possible to use both totally different url's for what seams to be the same page? Maybe you should share the `.htaccess` file and some PHP code which generates the page?

Comment: Rigth, i will update the question with the `.htaccess` file and php too

Comment: Redirect from the short form to the long form.

Comment: i added my htacces please take a look at it guys

Comment: @tadman how can i do that?

Comment: assuming both pages are the same, redirect 301 short url to the long one and make sure you fetch it in Webmaster Tools / Search Console